# Can't import programs from Idle - Pycharm or cross-platform at all? How can I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having some difficulty writing code on platforms such as IDLE and then importing/running them on terminal. The writing and executing is fine, but if I try to run-execute cross platform, ex. IDLE to PyCharm - or IDLE/PC to Terminal it does not work. My directory may not be formatted correctly. Here's an error I got:

> (null): can't open file 'spam.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This is on a Mac.

Comment: Please give the error message.

Comment: (null): can't open file 'spam.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: The file works and opens fine on IDLE where I created it but when I try to run/import on terminal i get this

Comment: please add new info to your post by editing it aside using comments

Comment: That `(null)` at the start is intriguing, and *may* point to an error elsewhere. When I enter a bad path (or none at all), I get `python: can't open file 'testtt.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.